# How to control login attempts in console application

Tags: c#, loops, console-application

- Request input of Username and Password from user
- If username and password is right, the program will display the output "Welcome".
- If username and password is wrong, the program will display the output "Try Again".

  - Then the user can enter again but up to 3 attempts only.
  - If user already entered 3 wrong attempts the program will display the output "System Blocked".

```cs
string uname = "user";
string pass = "word";

do
{
     Console.Write("Username:");
     uname = Console.Readline();
     Console.Write("Password:");
     pass = Console.Readline();
} while (uname!="user" || pass!="word");

Console.Write("Welcome User");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Please help,  I don't know how to add the attempts and ask the user to try again.

Comment: You can use a for loop or increment a counter in the current code.

Comment: use `if..else if` to check various conditions, use `break` to exit from the loop

Comment: You can define an `int attempt = 0;` variable before the `do`-`while`. Inside the loop you can increase it with 1 `attempt++`. You need to alter your `while` condition to check `attempt >= 3` as well. Finally you need to branch based on the number of attempts: `attempts >= 3 ? "System Blocked" : "Welcome"`

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can use an integer variable to determine the number of attempts. And 3rd time if user credential is wrong then break the loop with the desired message.
Note: `Console.Readline()` should be `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Hi, Caius. You are right. let me update my answer. I will give a hint then. Thank you